# Error when installing Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5 and MySQL via Homebrew

Tags: macos, install, homebrew, apache, php

I tried to install Apache and PHP on Mac OS X version 10.9.5

```
brew install httpd24 php55 --with-mysql --with-homebrew-apache --homebrew-apxs -v
```

exit with this error

> local/Cellar/apr-util/1.5.4/libexec/lib/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat -liconv /usr/local/Cellar/apr/1.5.1/libexec/lib/libapr-1.la -lpthread Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_TLSv1_1_client_method", referenced from: _main in ab.o "_TLSv1_2_client_method", referenced from: _main in ab.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Yosemite ships with apache 2.4.9, php 5.5.14 already installed, tuned up and ready to roll.

MySQL is readily available from their website in either tar or pkg format. It is a drop-in installation, php already knows about it. There is occasionally a socket issue, easily fixed by editing the php.ini file or just making a symlink.